# Make cucumber-jvm run all tests on Continuous Integration platform when kicked off via maven/command line

Tags: maven, command-line, continuous-integration, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Given someone has added the following to their RunTests.java:

```
@Cucumber.Options(
        format   = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json"},
        tags     = "@myTag",
        features = "src/test/resources/features"  )
```

Is there a way to make sure all scenarios are executed when running maven via a command line, e.g. on a continuous integration platform, like the following:

```
mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/features --tags @myTest"
```

Put differently, is there a command line option to force cucumber to "execute all features", e.g. using something like

```
mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/features --tags "
```

And am I correct in assuming

```
--tags ~@doNotRunMe
```

will execute all tags except the one mentioned?

If so, would

```
--tags ~@nonexistantTag
```

achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **Yes**, as pointed out by Björn in the [Cukes Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cukes/uFqIJ-zTDHE/FisCsNVAs38J).
He also [pointed out](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cukes/hd1Y-3enh_Y/4uuS73jpPk4J) that Cucumber-jvm supports AND and OR-like "links" for tags, and pointed me to the [Cucumber Hooks wiki page](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags), about which I had forgotten.